# DependencyProperty not being set on a field when the enter key is pressed

Tags: wpf, data-binding, dependency-properties

I have a usercontrol wit some textboxes on it.  Each text box has a dependencyproperty attached to the Text.  There is a button on the usercontrol that has it's IsDefualt value set to true.  If i type something into the text box and press enter the buttons click event gets fired but the DependencyProperty value is not set.  If I put in a break point the .Text has the value but the property does not.  However if I tab out of the field and then press enter the DependencyProperty does have the value.

How would I make the DependencyProperty have the value without the need to tab out of the field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the DependencyProperty to be updated as you type check out the [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx) property of your binding.

The default value for the Text property is LostFocus which means that the binding will not update your dependency property until the TextBox loses focus. Try:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```